# Create a new Central Administration Content Database

Tags: central-administration, content-database

Currently the Content Database for my Central Administration site has exploded to over 50GB, and expands to over 100GB everynight (leaving 50GB of free space). After much investigating I have determined I need to create a new Content Database and recreate the central administration. I have tried the following steps, however my central administration site failed to load:

1. psconfig.exe -cmd adminvs -unprovision //Remove Central Admin
2. stsadm.exe -o deletecontentdb -url [http://ectstspapp1:8000] -databasename SP_Content_Admin_1 -databaseserver TSTSQLCL2 //Removes Content DB from Central Admin Web App
3. stsadm.exe -o addcontentdb -url [http://ectstspapp1:8000] -databasename SP_Content_Admin_2 -databaseserver TSTSQLCL2 //Creates Content DB for Central Admin Web App
4. psconfig.exe -cmd adminvs -provision -port 8000 -windowsauthprovider onlyusentlm 
   After doing this Central Admin does not load, it comes to a 404. What am I missing?

Comment: If I were you, I'd restore backups and find out the root cause of your Central Admin content DB blowing up to over 100GB every night - I bet there's a config setting or a custom solution somewhere that's writing that much data, and even if you restore the Content DB for CA, it'll just keep filling up until you resolve the original problem.